# AngularJS and ng-style with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I have a problem using ng-style with ng-repeat.

This is my code:

```
<div style="display:table-row" ng-repeat="row in Data.Communications" id="{{row.Guid}}">
    <div style="display:table-cell;">
      <img ng-src="{{row.Path}}" ng-show="row.Path" ng-style="row.Style" />
      <i class="{{row.Icon}}" ng-show="row.Icon" ng-style="row.Style"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JSON (Loaded server-side from a DB):

```
$scope.Data: {"LastUpdate":"23/03/2016 11:45","Communications":[{"Guid":"2","Path":null,"Icon":"fa fa-warning","Style":"{'color':'#ffff00'}"},{"Guid":"1","Path":null,"Icon":"fa fa-warning","Style":"{'color':'#ffff00'}"},{"Guid":"3","Path":"/images/blink_yellow.gif","Icon":null,"Style":"{'width':'15px', 'height':'15px'}"}]}
```

The "Style" is not applied to my elements. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have strigified JSON, do parse it before assign it to `ng-style`

```
ng-style="doParseToJson(row.Style)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.doParseToJson = function(style){
   return JSON.parse(style);
}
```

Also make sure response should be wrap with `"` double qoutes instead of single quotes like `'{"color":"#ffff00"}'` to keep it valid for parsing the JSON.